# Add Android library project programmatically to Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm about to write a small and lightweight dependency management tool for Android projects. With it you'll be able to compile a list of jar files and Android library projects you will need. These jars and library projects should then automatically be downloaded and added to your project settings.

The "added to your project settings" part for Android library projects is my problem. Is there some sort of settings file (e.g. like the .classpath file) where this could be inserted? I couldn't find anything in the project folder.

To clear things up. I'm not talking about the ant build process. It's clear how to add library projects there. I'm only talking about the Eclipse settings for Android library projects.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For jars, add a classpathentry into the project's .classpath file, e.g.:

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/myjarlibrary.jar"/>
```

Note that the jar will need to be in the project's libs folder.

For Android projects, add them into the project.properties file, e.g.:

```
android.library.reference.1=../myandroidlibrary
```

(incrementing the number with each android library)

Comment: As far as I know, the project.properties are only used by the ant build process and are ignored by Eclipse. Am I wrong?

Comment: They are used by eclipse. Adding an Android library in Properies > Android > Library updates the project.properties as I described above.

Comment: Seems like I have overlooked that. I stand corrected. Thank you very much!